# O(lg(n)) * O(lg(n)) in complexity theory

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Stuck with some dumb question in complexity.

I have a loop that runs `O(lg(n))` time. I have another loop inside that is also `O(lg(n))` so the whole complexity is `O(lg(n)) * O(lg(n))` or **O(lg(n)<sup>2</sup>)**. Can I say that the final O is `O(lg(n))` because since n is a degree of 2 then

> O(lg(n)) * O(lg(n)) = O(lg(n<sup>2</sup>))=O(2lg(n))=O(lg(n))

or it can't be used this way?

Comment: it will be `O(lg(n)^2)` !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cant! because this:

> O(lg(n)) * O(lg(n)) = O(lg(n<sup>2</sup>))

is not correct. Although the rest is correct. so your loop is still ***O(lg(n)<sup>2</sup>)***

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought